# Unity3d NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: unity, c#

I'm making a script to climb ladders in my game.
These are the variables used in the function.

```
private Vector3 climbDirection = Vector3.zero;
private Ladder currentLadder = null;
private bool latchedToLadder = false;
```

And here is the function

```
void LatchLadder (GameObject latchedLadder, Collider collisionWaypoint){
    currentLadder = latchedLadder.GetComponent<Ladder>();
    latchedToLadder = true;
    climbDirection = currentLadder.ClimbDirection();
    gameObject.SendMessage("OnLadder",null,SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver);

}
```

Everytime I collide with the ladder in playmode i get

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UseLadder.LatchLadder (UnityEngine.GameObject latchedLadder, UnityEngine.Collider collisionWaypoint) 
UseLadder.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider other)
```

at

```
climbDirection = currentLadder.ClimbDirection();
```

Anyone can see what's the cause ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you're colliding with does not have the Ladder component. If you try to get a component from an object that doesn't have it, `GetComponent` will return null. You should check to make the sure component isn't `null` before doing anything with it, but you should probably make sure the object you're trying to latch on to is a ladder in the first place. You can do that by checking to see if it has the ladder component.

Before you call `LatchLadder`, perform a check similar to:

```
//inside your collide function
if(collidedGameObject.GetComponent<Ladder>() != null) {
    //it has the ladder component, it's a ladder
    LatchLadder(collidedGameObject, collisionWaypoint);
} else {
    //we've collided with something that isn't a ladder, do something else.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely latchedLadder has no Ladder component, in which case `latchedLadder.GetComponent<Ladder>();` returns null;